# MySQL Insert string with python inserts as individual characters

Tags: python, mysql, insert

I'm trying to do a simple insert with python

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="**",
  passwd="**"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO sponge_cakes.links (`url`) VALUES (%s)"
val = ("test1")

mycursor.executemany(sql, val)

mydb.commit()
```

This sort of works, but it inserts the string character by character (creating a new entry for each character)

How can I get it to insert the entire string so it looks like this

```
id  | link
1   | test1
```

Instead of

```
id  | link
1   | t
2   | e
...
```

Comment: why are you doing executemany? change that to execute and see what happens

Comment: `val` needs to be a _list of tuples_, `[('test',)]`.

Answer (score 0):

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO sponge_cakes.links (`url`) VALUES (%s)"

val = ("Dora")

mycursor.execute(sql, val)

mydb.commit() #make the changes

print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")

try it!.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using `mycursor.executemany(sql, val)` which is meant to run the same SQL statement with multiple values.

It might look like `"test1"` is just a single word, but a word can also be considered as a series of characters, and that's what `executemany` is interpreting it as.

Change it to `mycursor.execute(sql, val)` and it'll work as expected with a single value.